# Configuração de Tela e Teclado

Tags: android, android-layout

Bem, estou com uma certa dificuldade: Criei um formulário no android studio para inserir algumas informações, como na figura 1.

[image: imagem 1]

Em todos os campos, consigo inserir as informações sem problemas. Porém, quando vou inserir no ultimo campo (cujo hint é "insira uma descrição de seu evento"), o teclado cobre a visão, e não consigo visualizar o que está sendo digitado, mas o texto digitado é inserido, e consigo visualizar quando recuo o teclado.(Figura 2)

[image: imagem 2].

Inclusive ja tentei colocar um Scroll View cobrindo toda a pagina, mas não deu certo. Alguem tem a solução?

Segue em anexo o codigo xml

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/tipoDeEvento"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cidadeEvento" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nomeDoEvento"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Insira o nome de seu evento"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/logradouroEvento"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Insira o endereco do seu evento"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nomeDoEvento" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/cidadeEvento"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Insira a cidade de seu evento"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logradouroEvento" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/estadoEvento"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tipoDeEvento" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/botaoSalvarEvento"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Salvar"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView3"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/estadoEvento"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/descricaoEvento"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="117dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Insira uma descrição de seu evento"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/estadoEvento" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/valorEvento"
    android:layout_width="265dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tipoDeEvento" />
```

Comment: ta usando o `constraintlayout` ou o `relativelayout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geralmente uso o atributo `windowSoftInputMode` passando `adjustPan` como parâmetro. Veja:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Adicione isso ao seu `AndroidManifest.xml`, na *activity* em que está o `EditText`. Veja:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ActivityMain"
        ...
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        />
```

Comment: Desculpa, mas aonde coloco? Meu Manifest:

Comment: @LuísCarlos sim, no AndroidManifest.xml, em sua Activity onde está localizada o EditText.